# Do I have to request permission to record audio in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

According to `AVAudioSession` documentation, it seems that I no longer need to request permission. The information below states that the system automatically prompts the user for permission. But I've come across different answers while searching online.

### Documentation:

The first time your app’s audio session attempts to use an audio input route while using a category that enables recording, the system automatically prompts the user for permission. In iOS 7.0 and earlier, call requestRecordPermission: to prompt the user at a time of your choosing (see “Audio Session Categories”).

In iOS 8.0 and later, the user will not be asked to grant permission until the application attempt to use audio input.

After the user grants or denies permission, the system remembers the choice for future use in the same app. If the user has denied your app recoding permission or has not yet responded to the permission prompt, any audio recording sessions record only silence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to have the user grant permission to the microphone, but only when you attempt to use it rather than when the app is first launched. This is great for a plethora of reasons; the most valuable being that you can explain to your user why you need to use the microphone rather than blitzing them with permissions at launch!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still a bit confused, however, and have one more question. Why do I have to request permission if the system does it automatically? I don't understand that part.

Comment: Apple has guidelines to protect users, it does seem dumb initially, but think about it this way: You open an app and now an app has access to your microphone without asking. It records your conversations etc. and sends it to some server you didn't know existed. It's just a privacy precaution.